# cocos2dx cast Value to property string

Tags: c++, properties, cocos2d-x, tiled

I have defined a property as `tag` in tiled map editor, and what to retrieve that in cocos2dx

Here is how I do that:

```
for (int h=0; h< size.height; h++){
    for (int w=0;w<size.width; w++){
         auto sprite = layer->tileAt(Vec2(w,h));
         auto gid = layer->getTileGIDAt(Vec2(w,h));
         Value v = tmap->getPropertiesForGID(gid);
         ValueMap m = v.asValueMap();
         auto tag = m.at("tag");
         if (!tag.isNull()) {
           CCLOG(" tag string is %s", tag.asString());      
          }
   }
}
```

I was expecting the output to be like `blue, gray, black....` which is the tag I put in the properties of the tiled sprite, but the actually out is some thing like:

```
   tag string is ?SEgray
```

instead of

```
  tag string is gray
```

Some thing like that
I also tried this:

```
  tag.asString();
```

But that doesn't turn out to be right either.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out

I should use this

```
std::string type = tag.asString().c_str();
```

to cast to the final string, not sure what's `.c_str()` is, but it worked.
Thought should put it here to help some one meet with the same issue.

Comment: Hmm, that's very strange because [`Value::asString()`](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.0rc0/dc/dd1/classcocos2d_1_1_value.html#aa8535ea1f8f4f88ba32dcb36b6779ff2) already returns a `std::string`, so using [`c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) on it would only make this a little slower, since the new `std::string type` will need to determine the length of the string again. You should need the call to `c_str` only in the `CCLOG` statement, which likely works like `printf` and can't handle `std::string` (`%s` needs a `char*`).

Comment: @ThorbjørnLindeijer nice to meet you on StackOverflow man, truely, it is strange :D